# 404 error not found on images in relative path when deploying to surge

Tags: reactjs, vite, surge.sh

I am trying to deploy a vite react app to surge. It does not load my images from my images folder and I get a 404 not found error in the console for the images.

I have tried changing the domain name and double checked the paths. The images folder is in my public folder. All other images from an API i am using are fine. Anyone else had this issue or can help?

Answer (score 2):

I faced this error when i deployed on Netlify.

Try importing images instead of giving path

```
import image_name from "path-to-image"
```

or if you have so many images use Cloudinary to upload images
and use url

Comment: Importing resolved this.